# Except equivalent in python for nested dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, except

I have two large nested dictionaries in the form

```
dictOne = "key1": {
               "key2": {}
               "key3": {
                    "key4" : {data...}
               }
           }

dictTwo = "key1": {
               "key2": {}
           }
```

Except they are thousands of lines long some of the dicts are nested 10-15 levels in.
I want to find a way to combine them together similar to an EXCEPT in SQL. I want any keys that show up in dictTwo to be deleted from dictOne, but only if the dict under the key doesn't have children. 
So in this case the resulting dict would be

```
    dictRes = "key1": {
                  "key3": {
                      "key4" : {data...}
                   }
               }
```

I am assuming there is no easy way to do this, but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction towards making a method that could accomplish this

Comment: A 15 level deep dict?  This is not a good design.   Perhaps a code rewrite is more needed.

Comment: What is an example of your expected output?

Comment: it needs to represent a directory structure of a massive project. There isn't another way to do it unfortunately. @Ming dictRes shown above is what I would want it to output

Comment: To rephrase, is your expected output, "all nested paths in D1 with their original values which are not present in D2 regardless of value", or is it, "all nested paths in D1 which are not present with the same values in D2"?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question so far is extremely ambiguous about the general case behavior, so the above is a bit of a guess.

Comment: Yea I am sorry about I knew it would be ambiguous, but I wasn't sure how best to describe it. The final 'value' doesn't matter. All the matters are the keys. So if a key in D2 matches a key in D1 and the key doesn't have any children it should be deleted.

Comment: let me know if that doesn't answer your question

Comment: If you had to work with this, it'd be your best bet to just write a recursive function to go through this data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a recursive option.

```
def dict_parser(target, pruning):
    d = {}
    for k,v in target.items():
        if (not v) and (k in pruning):
            continue
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d[k] = dict_parser(v, pruning.get(k, {}))
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d
```

DEMO:

```
dictOne = {"key1": {
               "key2": {},
               "key3": {
                    "key4" : {"some stuff"}
               }
           }}

dictTwo = {"key1": {
               "key2": {}
           }}

dict_parser(dictOne, dictTwo)
# gives:
# # {'key1': {
# #     'key3': {
# #         'key4': {'some stuff'}}}}
```

Comment: Awesome, I think I can adjust this to fit my needs. Thanks a lot!